# Return object field by mention the object itself

Tags: c++

I want to create a class like "string" from "string.h"(STL).
My class is:

```
class MyChar
{
 char *Buff;
 public:

 /* Some constructors and other helpful methods */

};
```

My problem is, that I don`t know how to do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

 MyChar str;
 str = "My new string";
 cout << str;

}
```

I don`t want to mention "str.Buff" or "str.getBuffer()" or something ... just "str". Like the "string" class is.

Comment: I don't get people on this site. They upvote this question, which is ambiguous and poorly worded, and then close questions that are perfectly valid.

Comment: @TylerJandreau: That's because they're people. They each vote according to their own judgement, the aggregate of which is fundamentally illogical.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your class like that, you'll need what is called an "assignment operator". Wikipedia has a pretty good article [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C++%29)

Basically what you're trying to do is assign the right hand side (character array) to the left hand side (your class instance). You will need to overload the `=` operator, or, like a comment said, the `<<` operator.

**EDIT:** Since the OP downvoted me for not answering his obscure question "correctly", here is a snippet of a `<<` overload:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const MyChar& buf) {
    out << buf.Buf;
    return out;
}
```

And you would use it like this:

`std::cout << MyChar << std::endl;`

Granted, your class has to many problems for that to happen right now i.e., you don't allocate array space for the character array, so good luck!

Comment: No no. I`m not talking about the = operator. But the line: cout<<str; It don`t know what is it, or where is the string to display.

Comment: @АлександърДудев This: `str = "My new string";` is an assignment operator. This is what you're talking about.

Comment: Thank you! No my class is not what I posted. It is big, so I posted an example only for the question. I was wondering if there is a way not to define the operator for ostream, but it looks like a paradox :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the correct constructors and assignment operators. In this case variants which takes `const char*` as argument. You also need to overload the output operator.

You **definitely** need to learn about [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), and dynamic memory management.

Comment: @newbie: It's still just three as far as correctness is concerned. Move semantics are an optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overload the assignment operator `=` and the ostream operator `<<` for your class. A good article that I have found is [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/).

Comment: So, it cannot be done without predefine the ostream operator << ?

Comment: Of course not. How will the compiler know how to print to the output stream objects of your class?

Comment: I was thinking for something like the function`s "return". You mention a function, but it behaves like it`s returning type. It first performs the body. Then it use the returned data for the following code ... I was wondering is there something similar, which can be done with an object mentioning. Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add something like this: [not tested, but will give you an idea]

```
void operator=(const char *str )
{ 
    strcpy(Buff,feet, str);

}
```

following should be outside the class definition.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyChar& mch)
{
    os << mch.Buff;
    return os;
}
```

add  following statement to your class.
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyChar& mch);

Comment: The assignment operator should return `MyChar&`.

Comment: Yes. It is working. But "friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyChar& mch);" is unnecessarily. Thanks!

Comment: why did i get -1...please elt me know :(

Comment: I don`t know why, but I cannot vote, yet. But with "friend" you cannot define an operator :) And I think there is no way to add this operator defining to the header or to the class. Any ideas?

Comment: see this link   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx